# Setting up a FritzBox VPN via IPSec

Tags: vpn, fritzbox

I have the following problem: I have two houses. In both houses, I have an internet connection via a router. Now, I need to tunnel all (!) traffic from my network in house A to my home network's router in house B so that all traffic to a receiving third party's server seems to originate from the network in house B.

In house B, I have a dialup broadband connection with an IPv4 and IPv6 address that changes on a daily basis. The router is a FritzBox 7590 (https://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/fritzbox-7590/) which allows me to set up a VPN endpoint that exactly caters to my needs. The manufacturer AVM also provides a dyndns-like endpoint in the likes of `abcdef.myfritz.net` so that this VPN endpoint is always available even after the actual IP address changes.

Now, in house A I have a different router ("main router") I have little to no configuration power over. I don't want ALL traffic tunneled through to house B for performance reasons. So I have set up a second router (FritzBox 7530) in house A that creates a WiFi network and uses the "main" router as it's gateway to the Internet. The main router in house A has an IPv4 address, but no IPv6.

*WITHOUT* any VPN config, this works fine. As in "end device connects to WiFi of router 7530 and then the main router provides access to the internet".

My plan is as follows: the 7530-router in house A establishes a VPN connection "through" the main router to the 7590-router in house B. As the 7530 also creates a WiFi network, all devices logging into that second wifi network will implicitly use the VPN to house B, while all devices using the WiFi network of the "main router" are not tunneled at all.

All in all, it should look like this:

[image]

Now, I already configured the router in house B to function as a VPN endpoint (server) using IPSec. Using my credentials, I can use this VPN without any problems. Anyhow, this is only tested as creating a VPN connection on an end device (here: Macbook Pro) that then connects to the WiFi of the "main router" and the VPN tunnels through to house B.

Now, for the last step of my plan, I need to configure router 7530 accordingly (i.e., usign IPSec). And here is where the problems start:

The configuration for this is even described by the manufacturer: https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7530/5_Setting-up-an-IPSec-VPN-between-two-FRITZ-Box-networks/

This is the configuration page for the VPN (IPSec): [image: vpn config]. Whatever I enter, the connection is never established. I don't see how I can debug the issue properly. The logs are not really helping, as they state only:

`VPN error: VPN2BLN, IKE-Error 0x202D`

where the error is (according to the web) `IKE error 0x202D: dns: timeout`

Misc:

- Both routers (7590 and 7530) run the latest firmware 7.57
- main router network is 192.168.1.0
- 7590 home network is 192.168.2.0
- 7530 home network is 192.168.3.0
- The "main router" in house A cannot be configured. It provides Internet access for connected devices (including the 7530).
- Both networks in houses A and B dont have a fixed IP address
- The firmware also supports setting up a WireGuard VPN connection. OpenVPN etc is apparently not supported

My question(s) here are therefore:

1. How to set up the connection as intended?
2. Is there any flaw in the plan? (i.e. "how to make it better?)
3. How to ensure that no traffic is "leaked" to the Internet from house A (e.g. when the VPN connection fails for some reason)?

Thanks for reading that much :)

EDIT: Attempts in resolving the issues / lessons learned:

- When setting up the connection as described in https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7590/3331_Connecting-the-FRITZ-Box-with-a-company-s-VPN-IPSec/, end devices connected to the router 7530 have NO internet access al all (e.g. no DNS, HTTP, ICMP,... work). Pinging devices in the network of house B also fails. After deleting the VPN connection in router 7530, devices have internet access again.

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to configure OpenVPN as TAP versus IPSec - TAP is the same as using a switch to connect House A to House B, transparently passing traffic as if both houses were connected to the same router. OpenVPN also provides higher realworld throughput than IPSec, providing the highest VPN throughput when tuned and using TLS GCM ciphers, until WireGuard came along  _(WireGuard may work and is built into the firmware kernel of many routers/SBCs - I'm not a fan of it because of the lack of efficient solutions to encrypt the PSK, making it a massive inconvenience to secure)_

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Anyhow, as this is a FritzBox router with proprietary firmware/OS, I only have the options of using VPN via IPSec or WireGuard. OpenVPN seems not to be an option.
Furthermore, I need physical access to the router in house B to set up a WireGuard connection, which I currently cant do. Hence, I am trying to get the IPSec to run (which is already set up at house B).
I'll try looking into options for OpenVPN/Wireguard though.